# A ruby code to get input from user

Tags: ruby

kindly give an example, i am new to return number of ingredients. new to ruby and having prob with syntax.

```
class Recipe
  include Enumerable
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name, cuisine, ingredients, steps)
    @name        = name
    @cuisine     = cuisine
    @ingredients = ingredients
    @steps       = steps
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def cuisine
    @cuisine
  end

  def ingredients
    @ingredients
  end

  def steps
    @steps
  end

  def display
    puts "Recepie Manager"
    puts "\n Name:", @name, "\n Cuisine:", @cuisine ,"\n Ingredients and Quantity:", @ingredients, "Steps:", @steps 
  end

  def how_many_ingredients
    puts "Number of Ingridents:" , @ingredients
  end
end

obj1 = Recipe.new('Briyani', 'Indian','chicken,rice,spices,blah,blah','cook and eat')

obj1.display
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you're having? Just saying "having a prob with syntax" isn't enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As the previous comments say, your question needs to be more complete. We need to see working code, that is the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having. We need an explanation of the error or the reason it doesn't work, and we need the minimum input data necessary to replicate the problem. Finally we need to know what you expect to receive from the code. Without that we have to guess, try to reverse-engineer your code to come up with data and we have nothing to compare to so we can guage whether our code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

I used my guru "Google" for finding solution. For returning the ingredients count i used split and count methods.

```
def how_many_ingredients
    ingredients = @ingredients.split(",")
    puts "Number of Ingridents:" , ingredients.count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like you have misplaced your `end` statement. You have to create objects of class after it ends.

```
class Receipe
    include Enumerable
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name, cuisine, ingredients, steps)
        @name = name
        @cuisine = cuisine
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end

    def name
        @name
    end

    def cuisine
        @cuisine
    end

    def ingredients
        @ingredients
    end

    def steps
        @steps
    end

    def display
         puts "Recepie Manager"
         puts "\n Name:", @name, "\n Cuisine:", @cuisine ,"\n Ingredients and Quantity:", @ingredients, "Steps:", @steps 
    end

    def how_many_ingredients
        puts "Number of Ingridents:" , @ingredients
    end

end

obj1 = Receipe.new('Briyani', 'Indian','chicken,rice,spices,blah,blah','cook and eat')

obj1.display
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gets.chomp` to get input from users if thats what you mean

class Receipe
        include Enumerable
        attr_reader :name

```
    def initialize(name, cuisine, ingredients, steps)
        @name = name
        @cuisine = cuisine
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end

    def name
        @name
    end

    def cuisine
        @cuisine
    end

    def ingredients
        @ingredients
    end

    def steps
        @steps
    end

    def display
         puts "Recepie Manager"
         puts "\n Name:", @name, "\n Cuisine:", @cuisine ,"\n Ingredients and Quantity:", @ingredients, "Steps:", @steps 
    end

    def how_many_ingredients
        puts "Number of Ingridents:" , @ingredients
    end

end
yourname = gets.chomp
yourcuisine = gets.chomp
youringridents = gets.chomp
yoursteps = gets.chomp

obj1 = Receipe.new(yourname, yourcuisine,youringridents,yoursteps)

obj1.display
```